# Ag Grid angulr-setModel not working for multiple values

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Unable to filter based on array of values

```
onFirstDataRendered(params) {
const filterInstance = this.gridApi.getFilterInstance('country'); 
filterInstance.setModel({
      type: 'set',
      values: ['Brazil','Russia'] 
     })
     this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this you have a `agMultiColumnFilter` (assuming `agSetColumnFilter` is the second filter) filter:

```
 filterInstance.setModel({
    filterType: 'multi',
    filterModels: [null, { filterType: 'set', values: ['Brazil','France'] }],
  });
```

or if you have a simple `agSetColumnFilter` filter:

```
     filterInstance.setModel({
        values: ['Brazil','France'] }],
      });
```

Your data in the ag-grid should have the value of the filter.